# How to Compare if value repeated in the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns like this :

```
ChannelURI    UserId
1020            1
1040            2
1060            3
1020            5
1090            4
1020            5
```

now i want to check if any of the previous rows entries has the last value of the last row, if so and it has the same userID then skipped , if found (matched) and with different userId then insert null in ChannelUri

in this case `user ID =1` should have its `channeluri` set to `null`

any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous" and "last"? Those words assume that you have an ordering. What column are you ordering by?

Comment: when you say "insert null in ChannelUri" do you mean in the values returned by the query, or literally change the data in the table as one of the answers has (reasonably) assumed?

Answer (score 2):

SQL considers data to be an unordered set.  Unless you specify an ORDER BY the rows can legitimately be returned in any order at all.

Unless you also have another field(s) which you can order your data by, "the previous record" could actually be just about anything.

You *could* just select all the data and parse it in PHP or .Net, right?  ***Nope.***

Just because the data *usually* comes back in the same order, it's *never* guaranteed.  Changes to the data, fragmentation of data on the disk, indexes, parallelism and many other factors mean that the data can return in a different order at any time.

If your logic is dependent on the order of the data, you *must* specify an ORDER BY clause and so, by implication, must have fields in the data that enable you to order it.

Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a column `'Sort'` that you be used to order your rows by, the following statement would do the trick:

```
UPDATE m
SET ChannelURI = NULL
FROM mytable m
JOIN mytable m2 
  ON m.ChannelURI = m2.ChannelURI
  AND m.UserId != m2.UserId
  AND m2.Sort = (SELECT MAX(sort) FROM mytable)
```

Comment: +1 : However, if your assumption is true, I *think* this needs `AND m2.sort = (SELECT MAX(sort) FROM mytable)` or equivalent...  `check if any of the previous rows entries has the last value of the last row` *[Important part being `last row`.]*  Though I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: @Dems True, I've updated the answer. My version would make sure that ChannelURI would be unique per user, and not care about the last row as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this employs the same idea as [@erikxiv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421988/297408), but uses `SELECT TOP (1)` to retrieve the last row, instead of filtering on `MAX(sort)`:

```
UPDATE m
SET ChannelURI = NULL
FROM mytable m
JOIN (
  SELECT TOP (1) ChannelURI, UserId
  FROM mytable
  ORDER BY sort DESC
) last
  ON m.ChannelURI = last.ChannelURI
  AND m.UserId   != last.UserId
```